# Is there a way to pass arguments to a pkg

Tags: macos

I am wondering if it is possible to pass arguments to a pkg's Install scripts(preinstall/upgrade,postinstall/upgrade).  I noticed that when running my installer(my.pkg), my shell script do have access to some arguments($0-$3).

$0 = Script path 
$1 = Package path 
$2 = Default location 
$3 = Target volume

Would it be possible to pass additional arguments? If so, how would you do so on the command line?

Regards, 
-Jim

Comment: Using `launchctl setenv ENV_VARIABLE_NAME ENV_VARIABLE_VALUE && sudo installer -pkg pkgname.pkg -target /` we can pass arguments to installer.. But not to postinstall

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

`sudo MY_VAR=VALUE installer -pkg my_package.pkg -target /`

This has worked for me sometimes, but I'm still looking for a better way.

Carlos.

Comment: This does not work for me. Seems like the preinstall/postinstall scripts don't inherit the environment variables. Did this EVER work for you, @cyaconi?